# How to play a MIDI file in Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon (using any audio player)?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, music-player, midi

I'm trying to play a MIDI file in my Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon. I just open the MIDI file with **any music player** and it says it requires a plugin named **gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad**, so I click "Install" and then nothing happens, the player can't play the MIDI file.

I tried to install the plugin using **apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad** but it says **gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad is already the newest version (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1)**.

Any music player (including the "Video" application) says it needs this plugin every time I try to play a MIDI file, then just nothing happens.

OS: Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64 bit; Cinnamon version: 3.0.7; Kernel version: 4.4.0-38-generic.

Any idea?

Edit: The thing I need is playing a MIDI file using any audio player, I know there's VLC and its own plugin that can play MIDI file on its own, but what I need is playing a MIDI file using for ex. Banshee, Video or a professional audio producing software through a system plugin.

Comment: See the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MIDI#GStreamer-based_players_like_Totem_.28GNOME_Videos.29_or_Rhythmbox).

Comment: As wiki says: "You can play MIDI files on GNOME Videos and all other players using gstreamer as backend after having installed gst-plugins-bad (which provides fluidsynth as a dependency)". Unfortunately, this does not work for me.

Comment: Other thing I tried: apt-get install gstreamer*, then apt-get install fluidsynth*, still not working.

Comment: "... and correctly configured Fluidsynth with a sound sample."

Comment: I followed the wiki to configure Fluidsynth, but I couldn't follow it because I think it's already set in my system. I tired to install freepats but it appears to be already installed. Also I found that Timidity has been installed and it can actually play midi files via terminal. Instead, fluidsynth cannot play any midi files.

Comment: I still can't get it to work, I installed all the dependencies and I have set everything right, I have a soundfont (acoustic_grand_piano_ydp_20080910.sf2), When I exec **fluidsynth -a alsa -m alsa_seq -l -i /usr/share/soundfonts/acoustic_grand_piano_ydp_20080910.sf2 prova.mid** it acts like it's playing it and it returns to terminal when the track is over, but while it's playing it there's no audio outputting from the speaker or my headset neither. Timidity, instead, can succesfully output audio from my headset.

Comment: Fixed. **apt-get dist-upgrade** updated some things and it stopped to recognize my HDMI audio (which I don't use) and it weirdly started to output midi from my headset. It seems that it was **using my unplugged HDMI Audio output device instead of my primary audio output device!**

Answer (score 0):

As far I remember, you need to load the MIDI file (of the right instrument). This file generate the wave file from digital MIDI notation.  On older time, this file was proprietary (and with different quality across vendors), and distributed with the hardware. Now there are open files, but you need to select what kind of instrument do you want and play it.